# Mongodb indexing: 'key too large to index'

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

I have a dataset whose schema is like this:

```
{..., "url":"www.google.com", "time::143703672, "geo":"US-NJ", ...}
```

I want search documents by: (I'm using pymongo)

```
data.find({'url':url, 'geo':user_geo, 'time':{"$gt": userlog_gmt_time - 10, "$lt": userlog_gmt_time + 10}})
```

I tried to build a compound index:

```
db.AdxRevenueData_Jul.createIndex({url:1, geo:1, time:1})
```

However, I receive an error "key too long to index". The reason is that some url is extremely long. I believe that there are some "wrong" url in the dataset.

Then, I tried to build a compound index based on only 'geo' and 'time'. I thought I could iterate the return result and find the documents with the url. However, this method was too slow...

Someone suggested me to set parameters to skip those long urls.

```
sudo mongod --setParameter failIndexKeyTooLong=false
```

But, I am not sure if all long urls are wrong. I do not want to skip a lot documents.

My question is, is there any other solution, except changing DB?

For instance, should I use "text" index? Will it work?

```
db.AdxRevenueData_Jul.createIndex({url:'text', geo:1, time:1})
```

Or,
Should I additionally build url as a 'hashed' single index? Can it be a compromise?

```
db.AdxRevenueData_Jul.createIndex({url:'hashed'})
db.AdxRevenueData_Jul.createIndex({geo:1, time:1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using text index will not be helpful there.
I would recommend to use hashed index for this field.